# if field.choices change in a model, what happens to older records that have selections that are no longer in the list?

Tags: python, django

Would the data for these records be deleted automatically or left as they were? I'm wondering whether to use a seperate model to list these or if this is even an issue.

Comment: Validation of `choices` is *not* enforced at the database, so existing records will still have the old values.

Comment: perfect thank you, is there any way I can mark this as the answer?